# Why are tables not working right in these AngularJS directives?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS template file:

```
<div ng-controller="PredictionCtrl as predictionCtrl">
  <table width="40%" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="orange">A</td>
        <td bgcolor="yellow">B</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="pink">C</td>
        <td bgcolor="cyan">D</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <br>

  <table width="40%" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <rpt-my-directive-a p="1" q="2"></rpt-my-directive-a>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <rpt-my-directive-b r="3" s="4"></rpt-my-directive-a>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

In the template for my directive `myDirectiveA`, I have the following:

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
</tr>
```

In the template for my directive `myDirectiveB`, I have the following:

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="pink">G</td>
  <td bgcolor="cyan">H</td>
</tr>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I was expecting two identical-looking tables. Instead I got one with the proper colors and one without. Why did the table that was constructed using AngularJS directives come out looking different than the plain-HTML one?? How do I fix this? I want the second table to look just like the first.

**EDIT #1:**

When I took Sergey's advice below, the declaration for `myDirectiveA` now looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirectiveA',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        p: '=',
        q: '='
      },
      controller: 'MyDirectiveACtrl',
      controllerAs: 'MyDirectiveACtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<div ng-include="MyDirectiveACtrl.myDirectiveAHTML"></div>'
    };
  }
);
```

and the output now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With tables you need nest your elements correctly. So you cant nest custom tag inside tbody tag, the same with TR ... So please use attributes restriction for directives for that case.

Comment: Can you please show me the correct way to do it? I don't fully understand.

Comment: Have you tried <tr rpt-my-directive-a p="1" q="2"></tr>, and add to the directive declaration restrict: 'A' and replace: true ?

Comment: Replace your template with html where you have TR as a root, not a DIV. You cant nest DIV inside TBODY

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. As you can see in the original question, there are no nested DIVs. Both partial HTML files have TRs as their root.

Comment: You nest your rpt-my-directive tag, whats wrong. See my first comment. Im from mobile, cant help any more, sorry. Use as attribute your directive, not as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I couldn't comment On Sergey's answer. But I'm pretty sure he meant this: https://jsfiddle.net/a41o54ec

On this line:

```
template: '<div ng-include="MyDirectiveACtrl.myDirectiveAHTML"></div>'
```

That `div` needs to be a `tr`. And then I hope `MyDirectiveACtrl.myDirectiveAHTML` is something like `<td>whatever</td>`. I would recommend simply changing the template to this:

```
template: '<tr><td ng-include="MyDirectiveACtrl.myDirectiveAHTML"><td></tr>'
```

With `tr>td` in the template, the contents of `MyDirectiveACtrl.myDirectiveAHTML` can be almost anything.

## EDIT #1

If the template must contain several rows i would recommend creating an external `.html` and use `templateUrl` instead. Like this...

#### New file: myDirectiveA.template.html:

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
</tr>
```

#### On the directive definition remove `template:...` and do:

```
templateUrl: "path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html"
```

## EDIT #2

FAIL! on my part! It is true that when using `templateUrl`, myDirectiveA.template.html **MUST** contain a **single** parent element. That means that this:

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
  <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
</tr>
```

can't be done on the template... Since we are playing with tables, there's only a few elements that could be a parent for several `<tr>`. Being `<table>`, `<tbody>`, and a few others.

Since tables limit the element types you can use, you have to clearly define what you are doing with these directives. You reached a point where you have to decide if you are using a directive per row or a directive per table.

If you keep the directive as we defined it before, that means your template can only contain one row. We defined a **directive-per-row** model.

If you do want multiple rows on your template you must then apply the directive to `table` or `tbody`. **I** would do it to `table` and let **one** directive control the whole table.

```
<table width="40%" border="1"
  rpt-my-directive-a
  p="1"
  q="2"
  >
</table>
```

Also, remove this line from your directive definition. Otherwise, the `<table>` element will get replaced by the contents of the template.

```
replace:true // REMOVE ME!
```

By doing this... `myDirectiveA.template.html` can now have `tbody` as a parent element and the warning will go away.

```
// myDirectiveA.template.html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
    <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="orange">E</td>
    <td bgcolor="yellow">F</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Will this work if the directive's HTML contains multiple rows of <tr></tr> pairs? The reason I'm asking is because I'm using this to build a table. Some of the rows of the table are in `myDirectiveA` and some are in `myDirectiveB`

Comment: Yes... I created **Edit #1** to explain the use of tempalteUrl instead. I am guessing that you probably didn´t know **templateUrl** and maybe that's why you where trying to use ng-include? Anyways, let me know if the EDIT helps

Comment: Thanks Jairo!! `templateUrl` was very helpful! So was your fiddle. The only problem I'm having is that it when I change myDirectiveA.template such that it now conatinas two `<tr>` rows instead of one,  I get the following error: `angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'rptMyDirectiveA' must have exactly one root element. path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html`. What's the proper way to get around this issue??

Comment: Thanks Jairo!! templateUrl was very helpful! So was your fiddle. The only problem I'm having is that it when I change myDirectiveA.template such that it now conatinas two <tr> rows instead of one, I get the following error: angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'rptMyDirectiveA' must have exactly one root element. path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html. What's the proper way to get around this issue?? I posted this as its own question right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683523/angularjs-error-template-for-directive-xxxxxx-must-have-exactly-one-root-elem

Comment: TRUE! The template has to contain a single parent element. In our current case that means a single **tr**. Tables are tricky man. Please check out **EDIT #2**