# AngularJS error: Template for directive 'XXXXXX' must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, angular-directive

This is a follow-up to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673406/why-are-tables-not-working-right-in-these-angularjs-directives?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

I am trying to build and HTML `<table>` with multiple `<tr>` rows. I want some of these rows to be rendered by my directive `myDirectiveA` and others to be rendered by my directive 'myDirectiveB'.

Below you can see what my files look like. It all works fine if there is only one `<tr>` row in the file `path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html`. But as soon as I add another row in there, I get the following error:

```
`angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'myDirectiveA' must have exactly one root element. path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html`
```

Ok, so if I am allowed only to have one root element in that template file, then how can I construct my table with multiple rows from various directives? What is the way other people solve this seemingly-common use-case?

Here are my files:

**main.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
  <table width="40%" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr my-directive-a a="mainCtrl.a"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
myApp.directive('myDirectiveA',function(){
  return {
    'replace': true,
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': {
      'a': '='
    },
    'controller': 'MyDirectiveACtrl',
    'controllerAs': 'MyDirectiveACtrl',
    'bindToController': true,
    'templateUrl': "path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html"
  };
});


myApp.controller('MyDirectiveACtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return {'a': self.a};}, function (objVal) {},true);
  }
);
```

**path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html:**

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your directive template must be in simple `div` like `<div>you template...</div>` or any root element.

Comment: Guarav, I don't really understand your comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: your directive template must be inside root element.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684298/why-does-adding-an-ng-repeat-to-my-angularjs-template-break-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in the app

```
<table width="40%" border="1">
  <tbody  my-directive-a a="mainCtrl.a">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this in the directive template

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

It allows you to have only one root element in your directive, and add more than one TR inside of it.

Comment: But the problem is that sometimes when I use `my-directive-a` I want those rows to be in the `tbody` and other times I want them to be in the `tfoot` or `thead`. I can't have that tag hardcoded inside the template file of `my-directive-a`.

Comment: Like workaround may you use ng-repeat on your TR directive?

Comment: Or you may use template as a function in the directive and replace TBODY with some another tag

Comment: This works: `<tr ng-repeat="currRow in [0, 1, 2, 3] track by $index"><td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b</td><td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td></tr>`. THANKS!!!!! Now I can just put some specific logic inside the `<tr>` checking the value of `currRow` and doing something different in each case. EXCELLENT! (although such a shame that Angular forces me to use a workaround for this use-case)

Comment: I posted another follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684298/why-does-adding-an-ng-repeat-to-my-angularjs-template-break-it