# Why does adding an ng-repeat to my AngularJS template break it?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-template

I have an AngularJS directive whose template file looks like this:

**path/to/myDirectiveA.template.html**:

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>Statement</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
</tr>
```

It works. The output looks like this:

[image]

But then I change the template file by adding an `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currRow in [0, 1, 2, 3]">
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>Statement</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>{{currRow}}</td>
</tr>
```

And that causes it to break as you can see in the image below. The phrase `Hello World!` is no longer showing up! Why? How can I fix this problem??

I simply don't see any logical reason why adding an ng-repeat should cause this breakage. It doesn't make sense to me at all.

[image]

If you need it, here is the controller and directive that invoke it can be found in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683523/angularjs-error-template-for-directive-xxxxxx-must-have-exactly-one-root-elem) I posted earlier.

Comment: Is there any CSS modifying the `<tr>` and `<td>`?

Comment: dmlittle: There is no CSS involved.

Comment: i think this question will give an idea about your question problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573954/pass-parent-scope-value-into-ng-repeat-loop-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="currRow in [0, 1, 2, 3]">
<td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>Statement</td>
<td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b</td>
<td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{MyDirectiveACtrl.a.b}}</td>
<td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>{{currRow}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

update your myDirectiveA.template.html .Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I don't want this directive to be in a `tbody` all the time. Sometimes it will be in `tfoot`, sometimes in `thead` depending on where the tag is placed.

Comment: its working for me in either of those places .. have you tried it ?

Comment: No I haven't tried it. But nesting a `<tbody>` inside a `<thead>` doesn't seem like a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

may this solve the problem ($parent)

```
<tr ng-repeat="currRow in [0, 1, 2, 3]">
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>Statement</td>
    <td bgcolor='#ff1493'>{{$parent.a.b}}</td>
    <td bgcolor='#7cfc00'>{{currRow}}</td>
</tr>
```